# SQL Exception: Login failed for user

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, azure-sql-database

I have issues with my published Azure app service. Whenever I try to log in or sign up a new user, I get the error:

> SqlException: Login failed for user,
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception
> e)

My Azure database works when I run the app locally, which I'm assuming it's because it is using Windows to authenticate me. Based on my research, I think I have to individually grant each user access to my database once they are logged in, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Solutions I have seen that did not work:

- The Microsoft documentation I looked at wants me to edit web.config, which my project does not contain because it apparently is not automatically added to ASP.net MVC projects anymore.
- My connection string in apsettings.json does not set the values of `Trusted_Connection` or `Integrated Security`, so the user id and password in my connection string should not be ignored.
- Someone recommended setting `Persist Security Info` and `TrustServerCertificate` to true, but it is recommended to set `Persist Security Info` to false for security reasons, so this solution is not ideal.

My error message stack:

```
SqlException: Login failed for user 'ethanpart98'.
Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)
Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, uint waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, bool allowCreate, bool onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(bool errorsExpected)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(bool errorsExpected)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(bool errorsExpected)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable<T>+Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, bool result)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, TResult> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, ExecutionResult<TResult>> verifySucceeded)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable<T>+Enumerator.MoveNext()
System.Linq.Enumerable.Single<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
lambda_method36(Closure , QueryContext )
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute<TResult>(Expression query)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
System.Linq.Queryable.Any<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source)
Kickit.Controllers.HomeController.Validate(string email, string password) in HomeController.cs
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter<TResult>.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask<IActionResult> actionResultValueTask)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

My Login POST method in my controller:

```
        [HttpPost("Login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Validate(string email, string password)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var dbEmail = _db.Users.Where(u => u.Email == email).
                    Select(e => e.Email);
                var dbPassword = _db.Users.Where(p => p.Email == email).
                    Select(a => a.Password);

                if (!dbEmail.Any() || !dbPassword.Any())
                {
                    TempData["Error"] = "Error: Email or Password is invalid.";
                    return View("Login");
                }

                bool isValidPassword = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.
                    Verify(password, dbPassword.Single());

                if (dbEmail.Single().Equals(email) && isValidPassword)
                {
                    var dbFirstName = _db.Users.Where(u => u.Email == email).
                        Select(n => n.First_Name).Single();

                    var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("email", email),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, email),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, dbFirstName),
                };

                    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
                        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    var claimsPrinciple = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrinciple);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Habit");
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["Error"] = "Error: Email or Password is invalid.";
                    return View("Login");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Please give the full text from the SQL Server log, it contains `State` which is essential for diagnosing authentication failure

Comment: Are you using an azure sql dataabase ? are you using sql login or azure ad authentication? looks like you wann use user_impersonation as well ?

Comment: On Plesk I had to allow the webserver_user that runs the **aspnetcore application pool** access to the database. This sounds similar

Answer (score 1):

When a user connects using a Windows user account, SQL Server validates the account name and password using the operating system's Windows principal token. Because your SQL Database is housed in Azure, we must guarantee that both your SQL Database and. When using Windows Logins to connect to SQL Server, Net Core Applications are in the same Domain.

More information about Windows Authentication may be found at: [Connecting Using Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-2017#connecting-through-windows-authentication).

To resolve the issue you could opt for SQL server Authentication: SQL Server Authentication by pass the user name and password.

Even though the default connection timeout (not command timeout) is 15 seconds, increasing it to 60 seconds virtually never happens again. Simply add the following to your connection string: `;Connection Timeout=60` or more.

This can be a firewall issue. you can check the port in which the application is hosted.

Comment: Turns out it was a configuration issue in the Azure App Service. I had changed my password, and I updated all connection strings except for the one in my App Service. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Thanks for the update @EthanPartridge, Good to know that it got resolved :)